# This control cannot be displayed becuase its TagPrefix is not registered in this Web Form. [TopNavigationMenuV4]

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout, publishing

I had the opportunity of hiring a company to create a couple of layout pages for us. When I finally got them I get the following error message in SPD and the breadcrumbs are no longer showing up:

> Error Creating Control - TopNavigationMenuV4 This control cannot be
>   displayed because its TagPrefix is not registered in the Web Form.
>   Error Creating Control - TopNavigationDelegate This control cannot be
>   displayed because its TagPrefix is not registered in the Web Form.

What do I have to do to fix this issue?

Comment: Unlikely it's problem with menu. It migth be helpfull to view logs. Likely where are any other valueble information.

Comment: Oh, I will have a look at logs and come back.

Comment: Do you have the issue during run time or is it just in SPD?

Comment: Its only in SharePoint Designer. This doesn't affect browsing but I assume in a long this can have a serious negative on the layout itself.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too some long time back. Just a clue for you to look out for.

This might happen when you have controls with older versions referred. Like, there might be a situation that your master page or page layout is referring to a dll with an older version and a new version or more than one version is available in the assembly.

I am not sure, with your case, which control it can be, but it would be a good idea to verify the **versions** of assembly references you have included in the master page or page layout for any discrepencies. I hope that makes sense or let me know if you need more clarification.